# React + Tailwind - When clicked, a dropdown appears, but unfortunately it disappears right away

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

Task topic
In the top right corner, there is a User icon. When clicked, a dropdown appears, but unfortunately it disappears right away. This is caused by a collision issue between Tailwind animations and React rendering (I tested it with sample code, and this problem occurs consistently). You need to create a dropdown control that works seamlessly in the React environment.

The following will be useful for this:

- React State
- CSS animations
- Maybe some useEffect
- Handling

```
// @ts-nocheck
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  ArrowDownCircle,
  ArrowDownCircleFill,
  ArrowRight,
  Gear,
  House,
  List,
  PersonBoundingBox
} from 'react-bootstrap-icons';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Dropdown, initTE, Ripple, Sidenav } from 'tw-elements';

export const SideNavComponent = () => {
  const [dropdownVisible, setDropdownVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    initTE({ Sidenav, Dropdown, Ripple });
  }, []);

  const handleDropdownToggle = () => {
    setDropdownVisible(!dropdownVisible);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <header>
        <nav
          id="sidenav-1"
          className="fixed left-0 top-0 z-[1035] h-screen w-60 -translate-x-full overflow-hidden bg-white shadow-[0_4px_12px_0_rgba(0,0,0,0.07),_0_2px_4px_rgba(0,0,0,0.05)] dark:bg-zinc-800 xl:data-[te-sidenav-hidden='false']:translate-x-0"
          data-te-sidenav-init
          data-te-sidenav-hidden="false"
          data-te-sidenav-mode-breakpoint-over="0"
          data-te-sidenav-mode-breakpoint-side="xl"
          data-te-sidenav-accordion="true"
        >
          <span className="mb-3 flex items-center justify-center py-6 outline-none">
            <img
              id="alab-logo"
              className="mr-2 w-6"
              src="/logoalab.png"
              alt="Alab Logo"
              draggable="false"
            />
            <span className={'text-white font-bold text-[20px] pt-1'}>AlabFlow</span>
          </span>

          <ul className="relative m-0 list-none px-[0.2rem]" data-te-sidenav-menu-ref>
            <li className="relative">
              <Link
                to="/home"
                className="group flex h-12 cursor-pointer items-center truncate rounded-[5px] px-6 py-4 text-[0.875rem] text-gray-700 outline-none transition duration-300 ease-linear hover:bg-primary-400/10 hover:text-primary-600 hover:outline-none focus:bg-primary-400/10 focus:text-primary-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-primary-400/10 active:text-primary-600 active:outline-none data-[te-sidenav-state-active]:text-primary-600 data-[te-sidenav-state-focus]:outline-none motion-reduce:transition-none dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-white/10 dark:focus:bg-white/10 dark:active:bg-white/10"
                data-te-sidenav-link-ref
              >
                <span className="mr-4">
                  <House />
                </span>
                <span>Panel główny</span>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="relative">
              <a
                className="group flex h-12 cursor-pointer items-center truncate rounded-[5px] px-6 py-4 text-[0.875rem] text-gray-700 outline-none transition duration-300 ease-linear hover:bg-primary-400/10 hover:text-primary-600 hover:outline-none focus:bg-primary-400/10 focus:text-primary-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-primary-400/10 active:text-primary-600 active:outline-none data-[te-sidenav-state-active]:text-primary-600 data-[te-sidenav-state-focus]:outline-none motion-reduce:transition-none dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-white/10 dark:focus:bg-white/10 dark:active:bg-white/10"
                data-te-sidenav-link-ref
              >
                <span className="mr-4">
                  <Gear />
                </span>
                <span>Settings</span>
                <span
                  className="absolute right-0 ml-auto mr-[0.8rem] transition-transform duration-300 motion-reduce:transition-none [&>svg]:h-3 [&>svg]:w-3 [&>svg]:fill-gray-600 group-hover:[&>svg]:fill-primary-600 group-focus:[&>svg]:fill-primary-600 group-active:[&>svg]:fill-primary-600 group-[te-sidenav-state-active]:[&>svg]:fill-primary-600 dark:[&>svg]:fill-gray-300"
                  data-te-sidenav-rotate-icon-ref
                >
                  <ArrowDownCircleFill />
                </span>
              </a>
              <ul
                className="show !visible relative m-0 hidden list-none p-0 data-[te-collapse-show]:block"
                data-te-sidenav-collapse-ref
              >
                <li className="relative">
                  <a
                    className="flex h-6 cursor-pointer items-center truncate rounded-[5px] py-4 pl-[3.4rem] pr-6 text-[0.78rem] text-gray-700 outline-none transition duration-300 ease-linear hover:bg-primary-400/10 hover:text-primary-600 hover:outline-none focus:bg-primary-400/10 focus:text-primary-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-primary-400/10 active:text-primary-600 active:outline-none data-[te-sidenav-state-active]:text-primary-600 data-[te-sidenav-state-focus]:outline-none motion-reduce:transition-none dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-white/10 dark:focus:bg-white/10 dark:active:bg-white/10"
                    data-te-sidenav-link-ref
                  >
                    Profile
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li className="relative">
                  <a
                    className="flex h-6 cursor-pointer items-center truncate rounded-[5px] py-4 pl-[3.4rem] pr-6 text-[0.78rem] text-gray-700 outline-none transition duration-300 ease-linear hover:bg-primary-400/10 hover:text-primary-600 hover:outline-none focus:bg-primary-400/10 focus:text-primary-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-primary-400/10 active:text-primary-600 active:outline-none data-[te-sidenav-state-active]:text-primary-600 data-[te-sidenav-state-focus]:outline-none motion-reduce:transition-none dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-white/10 dark:focus:bg-white/10 dark:active:bg-white/10"
                    data-te-sidenav-link-ref
                  >
                    Account
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li className="relative">
              <a
                className="group flex h-12 cursor-pointer items-center truncate rounded-[5px] px-6 py-4 text-[0.875rem] text-gray-700 outline-none transition duration-300 ease-linear hover:bg-primary-400/10 hover:text-primary-600 hover:outline-none focus:bg-primary-400/10 focus:text-primary-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-primary-400/10 active:text-primary-600 active:outline-none data-[te-sidenav-state-active]:text-primary-600 data-[te-sidenav-state-focus]:outline-none motion-reduce:transition-none dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-white/10 dark:focus:bg-white/10 dark:active:bg-white/10"
                data-te-sidenav-link-ref
              >
                <span className="mr-4 [&>svg]:h-3.5 [&>svg]:w-3.5 [&>svg]:fill-gray-700 [&>svg]:transition [&>svg]:duration-300 [&>svg]:ease-linear group-hover:[&>svg]:fill-primary-600 group-focus:[&>svg]:fill-primary-600 group-active:[&>svg]:fill-primary-600 group-[te-sidenav-state-active]:[&>svg]:fill-primary-600 motion-reduce:[&>svg]:transition-none dark:[&>svg]:fill-gray-300 dark:group-hover:[&>svg]:fill-gray-300 ">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512">
                    <path
                      d="M144 144v48H304V144c0-44.2-35.8-80-80-80s-80 35.8-80 80zM80 192V144C80 64.5 144.5 0 224 0s144 64.5 144 144v48h16c35.3 0 64 28.7 64 64V448c0 35.3-28.7 64-64 64H64c-35.3 0-64-28.7-64-64V256c0-35.3 28.7-64 64-64H80z"
                    />
                  </svg>
                </span>
                <span>Password</span>
                <span
                  className="absolute right-0 ml-auto mr-[0.8rem] transition-transform duration-300 motion-reduce:transition-none [&>svg]:h-3 [&>svg]:w-3 [&>svg]:fill-gray-600 group-hover:[&>svg]:fill-primary-600 group-focus:[&>svg]:fill-primary-600 group-active:[&>svg]:fill-primary-600 group-[te-sidenav-state-active]:[&>svg]:fill-primary-600 dark:[&>svg]:fill-gray-300"
                  data-te-sidenav-rotate-icon-ref
                >
                  <ArrowDownCircleFill />
                </span>
              </a>
              <ul
                className="show !visible relative m-0 hidden list-none p-0 data-[te-collapse-show]:block"
                data-te-sidenav-collapse-ref
              >
                <li className="relative">
                  <a
                    className="flex h-6 cursor-pointer items-center truncate rounded-[5px] py-4 pl-[3.4rem] pr-6 text-[0.78rem] text-gray-700 outline-none transition duration-300 ease-linear hover:bg-primary-400/10 hover:text-primary-600 hover:outline-none focus:bg-primary-400/10 focus:text-primary-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-primary-400/10 active:text-primary-600 active:outline-none data-[te-sidenav-state-active]:text-primary-600 data-[te-sidenav-state-focus]:outline-none motion-reduce:transition-none dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-white/10 dark:focus:bg-white/10 dark:active:bg-white/10"
                    data-te-sidenav-link-ref
                  >
                    Request password
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li className="relative">
                  <a
                    className="flex h-6 cursor-pointer items-center truncate rounded-[5px] py-4 pl-[3.4rem] pr-6 text-[0.78rem] text-gray-700 outline-none transition duration-300 ease-linear hover:bg-primary-400/10 hover:text-primary-600 hover:outline-none focus:bg-primary-400/10 focus:text-primary-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-primary-400/10 active:text-primary-600 active:outline-none data-[te-sidenav-state-active]:text-primary-600 data-[te-sidenav-state-focus]:outline-none motion-reduce:transition-none dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-white/10 dark:focus:bg-white/10 dark:active:bg-white/10"
                    data-te-sidenav-link-ref
                  >
                    Reset password
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav
          id="main-navbar"
          className="fixed left-0 right-0 top-0 flex w-full flex-nowrap items-center justify-between bg-white py-[0.6rem] text-gray-500 shadow-lg hover:text-gray-700 focus:text-gray-700 dark:bg-zinc-700 lg:flex-wrap lg:justify-start xl:pl-60"
          data-te-navbar-ref
        >
          <div className="flex w-full flex-wrap items-center justify-between px-4">
            <button
              data-te-sidenav-toggle-ref
              data-te-target="#sidenav-1"
              className="block border-0 bg-transparent px-2.5 text-gray-500 hover:no-underline hover:shadow-none focus:no-underline focus:shadow-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 xl:hidden"
              aria-controls="#sidenav-1"
              aria-haspopup="true"
            >
              <span className="block">
                <List />
              </span>
            </button>

            <form className="relative ml-4 mr-auto flex flex-wrap items-stretch xl:mx-0">
              <input
                autoComplete="off"
                type="search"
                className="relative m-0 inline-block w-[1%] min-w-[225px] flex-auto rounded border border-solid border-gray-300 bg-transparent bg-clip-padding px-3 py-1.5 text-base font-normal text-gray-700 transition duration-300 ease-in-out focus:border-primary-600 focus:text-gray-700 focus:shadow-te-primary focus:outline-none dark:text-gray-200 dark:placeholder:text-gray-200"
                placeholder="Search (ctrl + '/' to focus)"
              />
              <span
                className="flex items-center whitespace-nowrap rounded px-3 py-1.5 text-center text-base font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200 [&>svg]:w-4"
                id="basic-addon2"
              >
                <svg
                  aria-hidden="true"
                  focusable="false"
                  data-prefix="fas"
                  data-icon="search"
                  role="img"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  viewBox="0 0 512 512"
                >
                  <path
                    fill="currentColor"
                    d="M505 442.7L405.3 343c-4.5-4.5-10.6-7-17-7H372c27.6-35.3 44-79.7 44-128C416 93.1 322.9 0 208 0S0 93.1 0 208s93.1 208 208 208c48.3 0 92.7-16.4 128-44v16.3c0 6.4 2.5 12.5 7 17l99.7 99.7c9.4 9.4 24.6 9.4 33.9 0l28.3-28.3c9.4-9.4 9.4-24.6.1-34zM208 336c-70.7 0-128-57.2-128-128 0-70.7 57.2-128 128-128 70.7 0 128 57.2 128 128 0 70.7-57.2 128-128 128z"
                  />
                </svg>
              </span>
            </form>
            <ul className="relative flex items-center">
              <li className="relative" data-te-dropdown-ref>
                <button
                  className="hidden-arrow flex items-center whitespace-nowrap transition duration-150 ease-in-out motion-reduce:transition-none"
                  id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                  data-te-dropdown-toggle-ref
                  aria-expanded="false"
                  onClick={handleDropdownToggle}
                >
                  <PersonBoundingBox className={'text-white text-[20px]'} />
                </button>
                <ul
                  className={`absolute left-auto right-0 z-[1000] float-left m-0 mt-1 ${
                    dropdownVisible ? '' : 'hidden'
                  } min-w-[10rem] list-none overflow-hidden rounded-lg border-none bg-white bg-clip-padding text-left text-base shadow-lg dark:bg-zinc-700 [&[data-te-dropdown-show]]:block`}
                  aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1"
                  data-te-dropdown-menu-ref
                >
                  <li>
                    <button
                      className="block w-full whitespace-nowrap bg-transparent px-4 py-2 text-sm font-normal text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 active:text-zinc-800 active:no-underline disabled:pointer-events-none disabled:bg-transparent disabled:text-gray-400 dark:text-gray-200 dark:hover:bg-white/30"
                      data-te-dropdown-item-ref
                    >
                      Mój profil
                    </button>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <button
                      className="block w-full whitespace-nowrap bg-transparent px-4 py-2 text-sm font-normal text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 active:text-zinc-800 active:no-underline disabled:pointer-events-none disabled:bg-transparent disabled:text-gray-400 dark:text-gray-200 dark:hover:bg-white/30"
                      data-te-dropdown-item-ref
                    >
                      Wyloguj
                    </button>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </>
  );
};
```